# How cancel angular http request made in RXJS Effects

Tags: typescript, angular8, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, rxjs-observables

I want to cancel the http request made in RXJS effects in angular 8.

```
@Effect() getReport$ = this.action$.pipe(
ofType(ActionTypes.GET_WIDGET),   
map(toPayload),
mergeMap(payload => {
  return this.dashboardService.getReport(payload).pipe(
    map(this.extractData),
    switchMap(result => {
      return observableOf(<ReceivedWidgetAction>{
        type: ActionTypes.RECEIVED_WIDGET,
        payload: result
      });
    }),
    catchError((err: Response | any) => {
      return this.handleReportError(err);
    }));
    
}));
```

Please let me know how i can do the same using angular 8. Also please note that I wont be able to use switch map as multiple angular components will be invoking this action with a different payload.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can cancel the ongoing request by using takeUnitil operator and creating the new action and dispatching the same action using the store whenever we need to cancel the request.

```
 @Effect() getReport$ = this.action$.pipe(
ofType(ActionTypes.GET_WIDGET),   
map(toPayload),
mergeMap(payload => {
  return this.dashboardService.getReport(payload).pipe(
    map(this.extractData),
    switchMap(result => {
      return observableOf(<ReceivedWidgetAction>{
        type: ActionTypes.RECEIVED_WIDGET,
        payload: result
      });
    }),
    takeUntil(this.action$.pipe(ofType(DashboardActionTypes.CANCEL_REQUEST))),
    catchError((err: Response | any) => {
      return this.handleReportError(err);
    }));

}));
```

Comment: Brilliant solution, I would just put the `takeUntil` operator to the bottom, as linter claims that no operator should be placed after a `takeUntil`

Comment: After cancellation, I can't seem to dispatch `GET_WIDGET` again. The effect isn't invoked anymore.